# Using sort() on specific Member of Struct after a sort()

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct

My Code is sorting a `vector<Struct>` accordingly to the Points the Player gained in the Game. This works fine. Now I wanted to add that if similar points, it sorts by time. So that the Person with the highest Points, but lowest time is on Top. My Problem lays in sorting the `vector<Struct>` without destroying the sort I did before for the points. Here is my Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Highscore{
    string Name;
    string Points;
    string Time;
};

Highscore parseToStruct(string data);
vector<string> Data = { "Ale, 01, 16", "Test, 10, 84", "Leon, 07, 61", "Cristian, 04, 43", "Kira, 09, 74", "Thomas, 01, 14", "Cooool, 05, 21", "Hohoho, 06, 56", "Neuer, 10, 81" };

bool compareByPoints(const Highscore &P1, const Highscore &P2){
    return (P1.Points > P2.Points) || (P1.Points == P2.Points && P1.Time < P2.Time);
}

vector<Highscore> sorting(){
    vector<Highscore> Test(Data.size());
    transform(Data.begin(), Data.end(), Test.begin(), parseToStruct);
    sort(Test.begin(), Test.end(), compareByPoints);
    //if I change compareByPoints with compareByTime it shows me the lowest time, but not in combination with Points
    return Test;
}

Highscore parseToStruct(string data){
    Highscore Style;
    vector<string> parse;
    stringstream s_stream(data);
    while (s_stream.good()){
        string substr;
        getline(s_stream, substr, ',');
        parse.push_back(substr);
    }
    Style.Name = parse.at(0);
    Style.Points = parse.at(1);
    Style.Time = parse.at(2);
    return Style;
}

int main(){
    size_t fieldWidth = 8;
    vector<Highscore> HighscoreList;
    HighscoreList = sorting();
    cout << " _________________________________________________\n"
        << "|                    HIGHSCORE                    |\n"
        << "|       NAME        |  POINTS  |  TIME (s)        |" << endl;
    for (const auto &Highscore : HighscoreList){
        cout << "|"
            << setw(fieldWidth + 10) << left << Highscore.Name << " | "
            << setw(fieldWidth) << left << Highscore.Points << " | "
            << setw(fieldWidth + 8) << left << Highscore.Time << " | " << endl;

    }
    cout << "|_________________________________________________|" << endl;

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
Thanks to @Lala5th was the solution quite simple and so I updated my Problem with the solution!

Comment: You can combine the two like: `[](const Highscore& a, const Highscore& b){ return (a.Points > b.points) || (a.Points == b.Points && a.Time < b.Time) }` into one single sort

Comment: Works perfect, how could I not see that simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lambda as custom comparator and do both points and time comparision in one function.

```
std::sort(Test.begin(), Test.end(), [](const Highscore &P1, const Highscore &P2) {
     if (P1.Points == P2.Points)
     {
         return P1.Time < P2.Time;
     }

     return P1.Points > P2.Points;
}
```

Comment: using [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) is simpler and less error-prone: `return std::tie(P1.Points,P1.Time) < std::tie(P2.Points,P2.Time);` it uses `operator<` of tuple which already implements the desired order

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number with your code, P1{20, 30} is better than P2{20,25}. Its wrong, beacuse with same points, less time is better.
With your idea - `std::tie(P1.Points, P2.Time) < std::tie(P2.Points, P1.Time)` will work. Now P2{20,25} is better than P1{20, 30}.

Comment: oh right, `std::tie` won't work, but you can use `return std::make_tuple(-a.Points,a.Time) < std::make_tuple(-b.Points,b.Time);`

Comment: ...but for that OP would need to turn the strings to `int`s

Answer (score -2):

You just need to add a check within your compareByPoints function.
If the Points are identical, check for time.

Comment: See answer by @Marciej_Adamski - That's one way of implementing it.